How do I restore a supabase db from a .backup file?
I have been handed a .backup file and I want to import it into my own supabase project but there doesn't seem to be a way to do so. I do not have admin access to the original db and I can't get it in any reasonable amount of time. I want to simply switch to my own account and import the backup from the old project/db/supabase instance. How do I do this?
